# Using ::after on an H2 header to display an "up" arrow to return to the top of the page. How do I make it reference the <a name=> when clicked?

Tags: javascript, css, html

```css
h2::after {
    content: '\25b2';
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    font-size:1.2em;
    cursor: pointer;   
}
```

```html
<h2>Example</h2>
```

This is what I have.  I want to make it so that when the up arrow is clicked it returns to the top of the page.  I have  defined at the beginning of the content.  How can I accomplish this?  I would prefer straight CSS, but JS is acceptable if that's the only way.

Comment: Can’t you insert a real `a`-element into the `h2`-Element?

Comment: `CSS` can't handle such things. You can use JavaScript or just put an `a` tag inside that `h2` element, and style it as you want, 
 give it `href="#"` it will jump to the top when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others. Have a look at the following example. This example does use es6 functions meaning that you need something like bable before you can use it in IE if that is what you want.

```js
const headers = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('h2') );

headers.forEach( header => {
  header.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', 
   '<a href="#">&#x25B2;</a>'
  );
});
```

```css
h2 a {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  font-size:1.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<h2>Example1</h2>
<h2>Example2</h2>
<h2>Example3</h2>
```